# Twitter call back url not working in android

Tags: android, callback, twitter

Now i try to Implement Twitter Integration in android using **twitter4j** library.Few months back I successfully implemented this using a dummy call back url like "**PicPuzzle://tkxel**".

But now Twitter changes its scheme and now  not allow to create application with dummy URL.

Now the problem is after authentication It redirect to callbackurl But not return to application.

I specify the same url in application and registration page. I refered [Problem in Callback in Twitter in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813996/problem-in-callback-in-twitter-in-android) and [How I can call back in Android using OAuth for Twitter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644239/how-i-can-call-back-in-android-using-oauth-for-twitter). But these solutions are now not working because now twitter not allow to create application with dummy URL. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: you can check callback url and then close the webview

Comment: use "x-oauthflow-twitter://callback" as a callbak url.

Comment: @DipakKeshariya now twitter not allow to set the callback url as x-oauthflow-twitter://callback..

Comment: @Ajmal But this callback url is working in my application.

Comment: @VivekKumarSrivastava Where we check this when using twitter4j. few months back it by default detecting dummy callback urls and closing the web view. Now its not happening. thanks.

Comment: @DipakKeshariya Also worked in me few months back.That application also working fine now. Now i want to create a new application but now twitter now not allowing set callback urls like that.

Comment: @Ajmal i am testing now and it is working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13668/discussion-between-ajmal-and-dipak-keshariya)

Comment: @Ajmal please come in chat room.

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps:

1. Go to Twitter Apps: https://apps.twitter.com/
2. Then, Go to your app.
3. Go to Settings Tab
4. In section "Callback URLs", add the below line:

> twittersdk://

5. Click button "Update Settings" at the bottom. That's it.

Hope this works!

Comment: I Tried your solution it does not work for me can u suggest any other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create your own WebViewClient subclass.
2. Override shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) method.
3. In shouldOverrideUrlLoading(), check if url.startsWith(YOUR_CALLBACK_URL) is true.
4. If true, retrieve "oauth_verifier" parameter from the URL and return true (true from shouldOverrideUrlLoading() prevents the WebView instance from loading the URL).
5. Get an access token using the value of the parameter obtained in the step 4.

Your application can get control back from the WebView instance after the step 4.

If the above steps sound cumbersome, try [TwitterOAuthView](http://darutk-oboegaki.blogspot.jp/2012/07/twitter-oauth-view-for-android-using.html). Its usage is very simple. Just call

```
view.start(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, CALLBACK_URL, true, listener);
```

and receive the result via TwitterOAuthView.Listener interface defined as below.

```
void onSuccess(TwitterOAuthView view, AccessToken accessToken);
void onFailure(TwitterOAuthView view, TwitterOAuthView.Result result);
```

If true is given to TwitterOAuthView.start() method as the forth argument, TwitterOAuthView does not access the callback URL, and I think this behavior is what you want to implement. The source code, [TwitterOAuthView.java](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/TwitterOAuthView/blob/master/src/com/neovisionaries/android/twitter/TwitterOAuthView.java), may be of help.